# How to make SAS Enterprise Guide show only the latest data created in Output Data?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

Also how to make SAS Enterprise Guide to go to Output Data tab after a successful run instead of Results tab?

Answer (score 0):

It's going to go to Results if you produce results, I don't think there's any way around that. You will get all of the datasets produced in that program in the Output Data tab, as well.

However, I'm going to venture a guess here: you're using EG like a single window programming environment, right?  You have a single long program?  If so, then the answer is simple: split your program up.  EG is intended to have lots of small programs, each of which have a very specific goal and output.  Think of it as steps: each program node is just one step, could be even just one data step. Then you link several programs together, in sequence, and run them all as a process flow (or an ordered list).

If you treat it that way, then it works very much like you say: you can have one program that has one output dataset and no results window, if your last program in a process flow just produces one dataset and no results.